# html link tr broken not on place

Tags: php

I've tried making my hole `tr` tag to be clickable so I made this code

```
        <?php foreach ($data['forums'] as $forum): ?>
            <?php #var_dump($forum); ?>
            <tr class="fix head">
                <th class="fix ltext"><strong><?php echo $forum['name'] ?></strong></th>
                <th class="fix rtext"><strong>Trending</strong></th>
                <th class="fix ltext"><strong>Latest Post</strong></th>
            </tr>

            <?php foreach ($forum['children'] as $child): ?>
            <?php #var_dump($child); ?>
                <tr class="fix">
                    <a href="#">
                        <td class="fix ltext cl">
                            <strong><?php echo $child['name']; ?></strong>
                            <p><?php echo $child['description_html']; ?></p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fix rtext cr">1423</td>
                    </a>
                    <td class="fix ltext cr cl">
                        tanya jawab sesuatu by <a class="u" href="#">=awdwad</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
```

on the view

The problem is

[image]

The link should be just above the highlighted part and below it. How could it be above far away, below my body tag?

**Does ayone have any experience that could possibly generate this error?**

Comment: Have you tried to escape your data? I mean like htmlentities($child['name']);

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa yes, but there is no html on that side. thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that that is an invalid place for an `<a>`. *No* DTD will allow what you have tried to do.

Your approach is all wrong. You have to use Javascript to make a whole `<tr>` clickable. AFAIK, there is no way to do this in any HTML variant alone.

Try something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr id="my_clickable_tr">
    <td>Stuff</td>
    <td>Stuff</td>
    <td>Stuff</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- More table stuff -->
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('my_clickable_tr').onclick = function () {
    window.location.href = 'http://wherever.you.want/to/send/the.clicker';
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you've put the `a` tag where it's not allowed, so any browser's answer is legitimate. You should put an `a` into each `td`. Perhaps, you may alternatively handle click event for `tr` element, but that would require javascript.

Comment: `<a href="#"><td>test</td></a>` fails to btw.

Comment: Well it will. Your would need to do `<td><a href="#">test</a></td>`. An `<a>` is a block-level element and is not allowed as a direct child of a `<tr>`. But the javascript approach is probably what you need here.

Comment: thankyou!, maybe others would like to see the example too, it work for me. so placing the js on above. thanks again micheal and dave.

Comment: Ah, I see Dave elaborated on my javascript proposal. Yes, that's good answer. I'd do it like `<tr onclick="windows.location.href='...'">` — easier if you have many `tr`s. Also, you may want to style the cursor for these `tr`s.

Answer (score 1):

Anchor tags (`a`) are not allowed as children of table row (`tr`) tags, see the documentation [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-TR). Only table header (`th`) and table data (`td`) tags are allowed.